# How does convergence imply continuity?

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be metric spaces and let $f : M \rightarrow N$ be a map. Show that $f$ is continuous if an only if it takes convergent sequences to convergent sequences and limits to limits, that is, if and only if $x_i \rightarrow x $ in $M$ implies $f(x_i) \rightarrow f(x) $ in $N$.

I don't really understand what convergence has to do with continuity. In an effort to understand this better I've come up with a counterexample.

$$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\f(x) = 2x+IntegerPart[x]$$

Let: 
$$x_i= \sum\limits_{n=0}^i  ( \frac{4}{5})^n  $$
Thus when $x_i \rightarrow 5, f(x_i) \rightarrow f(5)=15$. $f$ is not continuous at 5, but it seems to be converging.

The chart blow shows the $x_i$ sequence in red and the $f(x_i)$ sequence in green: 
[image]

How does convergence imply continuity?

Comment: what if you choose $X_n=5-(1/n)$?

Comment: Try using proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things here.

Your "counterexample" isn't a counterexample: $f(x_i) \to 14$, not 15. Indeed, if $x_i < 5$ then $2 x_i + \text{Int}(x_i) < 10 + 4 = 14$.

Secondly, even if it did converge to the right thing (15), that still wouldn't be enough to show that the function wasn't continuous. Continuous iff *all* sequences have $f$ tending to the right thing, and discontinuous iff *some* sequence has $f$ tending to the wrong thing. Showing that one sequence tends to the right thing tells you nothing.

Comment: I felt like I was doing something wrong with the "counterexample" (I was putting too much faith in the computer output.) <p> Does the function in my example sufficiently prove the f is not continuous?</p>

Comment: The computer's output is entirely correct, but it doesn't show what you say it shows: it shows "$f(x_i)$ tending to 14", not "tending to 15". Yes, there's a data point at 15, but there's just one of those.

Comment: Also if I change $f:\mathbb{N}→\mathbb{R}$ and keep the rest that same, is the function now continuous?

Comment: Yes: it becomes the function $f: x \mapsto 3x$.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can start by contradiction.

Assume f is not continuous at some point $x_0$. This implies $f(B_\delta(x_0))$ is not contained in $B_\epsilon(f(x_0))$. Now consider the sequence $$\{x_n\}= (B_1(x_0), B_1/2(x_0),\cdots,B_1/n(x_0),...)$$ You can see that this $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_0$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$. This breaches what we had said 
in the contradiction.

Hence proved